# Recomendation on storing data in share preference in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sharedpreferences

I am new in share preference so kindly forgive me this silly question. I am developing an application in which I have to fetch data from xml and all data are in text form,  So I think I'll store this all data into shared preference because this is quite light weighted and not too much so thats why not going for sqlite. So before jumping into this approach I want to know is that good approach or not and what are recommendations on storing data in share preference?

Answer (score 2):

To store data:

```
NSString *someValue = @"someval";

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:someValue forKey:@"nameOfSomeValue"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

To retrieve it later:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *someValue = [defaults valueForKey:@"nameOfSomeValue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is an Android thing, and your question seems to be about iOS.

You can store user preferences and other lightweight data in `NSUserDefaults` on iOS, as described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623937/834998).

If you want to store data in XML files, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623678/834998) provides a helpful example.